# Circle packs as nodes of a D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout, circle-pack

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/4eru2/):

[image]

This is really good if you have, let's say, 2 political parties, and you want to present election results across several voting units, or similarly structured data.

However, I need to visually represents this: (5 political parties instead of 2) *(please  ignore all raws except "seats"; only "seats" are supposed to be visualized)*

[image]

I would like to have a `circle pack` inside each `force layout node`.

For example, there should be a balloon called BC containing four smaller circles with areas proportional to 21, 12, 2, 1 (one political party didn't win any seat in BC - British Columbia), and so forth for all provinces in Canada.

Could you tell me if this is possible and/or outline code organization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strategy should be more or less: Format the data structure to reflect that hierarchy:

```
{
    name: 'Election Results',
    children: [
        {
            region: 'BC',
            children: [
                {party: 'Conservative', seats: 12},
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And compute the Pack Layout for this data, but don't draw any circles yet. This will give you the size for each region, in the nodes where `depth === 1`. Now you can compute the force layout. To avoid one region overlapping another one, you should set the charge to be proportional to the area of each region (proportional to `Math.pow(d.r, 2)`.

Now, you can create one group for each node where `depth === 1` (the regions), setting the position given by the force layout.

For each group, compute a new pack layout, setting the size of each one to twice the radius of the region. You can now create the circles in a subselection of the groups selection, giving each one the radius set by the second pack layouts. Finally, I would create a class for each party, so you can style each bubble differently. Perhaps the same should be done for the group circles.

That said, I would rather use just the bubble layout, or having a pack layout for the regions with multi-foci force layout for the party circles.

Comment: That's really cool! Unfortunmately, I don't have much time at this moment, but will try what you said as soon as I am free. Upvoting immediately, because you sensed exactly what I need (outline of the solution). Will be back with finished solution later on.

Comment: Hey @VividD Can you please help me with an example ? How did you implement this thing, as i am stuck at similar problem. Not able to figure out how to proceed ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67002241/how-to-combine-force-layout-and-packed-layout-in-d3