# Label placement outside circles without overlap using layout.pack

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, overlap, circle-pack

I'm very new to d3 and I'm building a chart using d3.layout.pack.

I would like to place the text labels of every circle outside the circle, but without overlapping other labels or other circles.

Like this:
[bubble chart using d3.layout.pack](http://i1098.photobucket.com/albums/g368/sergioshernand/circlepacklayout_zpsb8a1ecf4.jpg)

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

pd: [this is](http://jsfiddle.net/9x2Wj/) what i've tried:

```
var nodes = d3.layout.pack()
  .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .size([w, h]).padding(333)
  .nodes(data);
```

Comment: Always show what you've tried.

Comment: updated, sorry for not to show what i've tried but i think it's not relevant

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach: to place `labels/text` along the top of the circles, and only for fairly large circles... This will not solve overlap problem completely, but visual organization will be better, in my opinion.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/zGME5/) of an example illustrating the approach.

[image]

The details are described in [another SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255967/text-along-a-circle-in-a-d3-circle-pack-layout)