# d3.layout.pack text inside circle overrides other text in other circle

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, circle-pack

I'm using d3.layout.pack to place circles inside other main circle, like in http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/pack.html

[image]

But i have larger texts inside circles that override the circle and can override another text in a near circle:

[image]

The solutions I can think are:

- cut text for not to override the circle
- put smaller font for the circles.
- set greater padding
- put a tooltip onmouseover the circle
- rotate text??

But that ideas doesn't satisfy me too much. I will like for example in this case to place the two smaller balls more spaced.

Can `d3.layout.pack` do some more interesting avoiding the circle overriding?

Can I use `d3.layout.force` for this? Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK you can't do anything in the pack layout to avoid this (apart from making everything bigger/the text smaller). You could use the force layout to position the labels, but this is likely to be quite a bit of additional effort.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest as one of possibilities the answer to [question 'Text along a circle in a D3 circle pack layout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255967/text-along-a-circle-in-a-d3-circle-pack-layout):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/zGME5/)

[image]

Basically, the `idea` is to draw labels along the circles instead in the centers of the circles. Also, you might consider drawing only some of the labels at the time - those that belong to small circles maybe should be omitted.

Comment: Can you help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485975/how-do-i-arrange-all-bubbles-in-circular-manner-in-bubble-chart-with-force-layou

Comment: After some research on d3 circle pack text truncation, I found that many pplwant to fix it, but few found a satisfying solution. There is this textwrap method, but it fails on long words. Also with group labels that are centered, it can be hard to see which group is described. So this solution here is actually very elegant, ince it gets around those issues.